# How to count totals and uniques (based on 2 separate columns) using ArrayFormula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have the following spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pBL21fyuxYNb5YfERsFl7Y-CTdQEH7SgJQfuOdQ0V6c/edit?usp=sharing

The first 2 columns count the total number of actions and sort them. What I want to do is also generate the next 2 columns using the same formula. The 3rd column is meant to count the unique number of actions based on user id, and the 4th column is meant to count the unique number of actions based on the user name. I can do a formula that counts the uniques separately, but ideally, I would like it to work together with the first 2 columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share how the sheet used to be for historical purposes, as now it has updated data. Or a screenshot if possible. Thank you @darkhorse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following formula in cell A10 or any free cell except in columns F,G and H:

```
=arrayformula({query({F3:F,F3:F},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Total'",1),iferror(vlookup(query(query({F3:F,F3:F},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Total'",1),"select Col1"),query(query({F3:G,G3:G},"select Col1,Col2,count(Col3) where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col2 label count(Col3) 'Total'",1),"select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Unique (for id)'",1),2,0)),iferror(vlookup(query(query({F3:F,F3:F},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Total'",1),"select Col1"),query(query({F3:F,H3:H,H3:H},"select Col1,Col2,count(Col3) where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col2 label count(Col3) 'Total'",1),"select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Unique (for name)'",1),2,0))})
```

To get sorted (by column 2) result, try:

```
=arrayformula({query({F3:F,F3:F},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc label count(Col2) 'Total'",1),iferror(vlookup(query(query({F3:F,F3:F},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc label count(Col2) 'Total'",1),"select Col1"),query(query({F3:G,G3:G},"select Col1,Col2,count(Col3) where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col2 label count(Col3) 'Total'",1),"select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Unique (for id)'",1),2,0)),iferror(vlookup(query(query({F3:F,F3:F},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc label count(Col2) 'Total'",1),"select Col1"),query(query({F3:F,H3:H,H3:H},"select Col1,Col2,count(Col3) where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col2 label count(Col3) 'Total'",1),"select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Unique (for name)'",1),2,0))})
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly, but it does not sort the columns based on the value of the second column, ie, total.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({F3:H, 
 IF((G3:G<>"")*(COUNTIFS(F3:F&G3:G, F3:F&G3:G, ROW(G3:G), "<="&ROW(G3:G))=1), F3:F&G3:G, ),
 IF((H3:H<>"")*(COUNTIFS(F3:F&H3:H, F3:F&H3:H, ROW(H3:H), "<="&ROW(H3:H))=1), F3:F&H3:H, )},
 "select Col1,count(Col1),count(Col4),count(Col5) 
  where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)'Total',
        count(Col4)'Unique (for id)',
        count(Col5)'Unique (for name)'", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: What if the "Id" column was in column H and the "Name" column was in column I? What would you change to your formula to make sure it still works correctly? Sorry if this the wrong place, I can post another question if you want.

Comment: it would be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({F3:H, 
 IF((H3:H<>"")*(COUNTIFS(F3:F&H3:H, F3:F&H3:H, ROW(H3:H), "<="&ROW(H3:H))=1), F3:F&H3:H, ),
 IF((I3:I<>"")*(COUNTIFS(F3:F&I3:I, F3:F&I3:I, ROW(I3:I), "<="&ROW(I3:I))=1), F3:F&I3:I, )},
 "select Col1,count(Col1),count(Col4),count(Col5) 
  where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)'Total',
        count(Col4)'Unique (for id)',
        count(Col5)'Unique (for name)'", 1))`

Comment: The formula you corrected worked perfectly. One weird thing I noticed was that if the action is not a string, then the formula stops working. Is there a way to incorporate `TOTEXT` into this formula so that the action column is always converted into a string?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({F3:H, IF((H3:H<>"")*(COUNTIFS(F3:F&H3:H, F3:F&H3:H, ROW(H3:H), "<="&ROW(H3:H))=1), F3:F&H3:H, ), IF((I3:I<>"")*(COUNTIFS(F3:F&I3:I, F3:F&I3:I, ROW(I3:I), "<="&ROW(I3:I))=1), F3:F&I3:I, )}), "select Col1,count(Col1),count(Col4),count(Col5) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)'Total', count(Col4)'Unique (for id)', count(Col5)'Unique (for name)'", 1))`